# Function to save values in SQL database

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite

I want to understand the following JavaScript function better. Would be great if you could help me.

```
function createevent(id, number, callback) {
    let sql = `INSERT INTO event (id, number, status) VALUES (?,?, 'outstanding')`
    let params = [id, number]

    db.run(sql, params, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message)
            callback(true)
        } else callback(false)
    })
}
```

- Why exactly is "let params" for?
- what is happenning with "db.run"?

Comment: let params are creating an array with id and number so that you can pass to your DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `let` is a keyword used to declare a variable in modern javascript, before that `var` keyword is used.
2. `db.run()` will be used to run the sql command so new record can be added to database. It takes 3 parameters

   1. sql command  : here it is `INSERT INTO`
   2. parameters : actual values that goes into placeholder '?' symbol in sql command, thus completing sql command as `INSERT INTO event (id, number, status) VALUES (id, number, 'outstanding')`. values of id and number is parameter values.
   3. callback function : function that is returned by `db.run()` after execution of command. We can detect if any error happen by checking the value returned by callback function.

```
// Variable declarations
let sql = `INSERT INTO event (id, number, status) VALUES (?,?, 'outstanding')` // save sql command to variable named sql
let params = [id, number] // save id and number as array to variable named params 

// Run SQL command
db.run(sql, params, (err) => {        // passing saved values and function to get error status
    if (err) {                        // check if error happened
        console.error(err.message)    // if yes print error message to console
        callback(true)                // and return true to callback function
    } else callback(false)            // else return false to callback function
})
```

Answer (score 0):

instead `let` better use `const` in this case,
let use for variables what can reassigned in current scope

db.run prepare sql, send to db, await response pass response to your callback

prepare sql,
sql have - ?, everyone concide with one param, first ? to first param ...
in during prepare sql, ? replaced with params

you don`t can write it

```
  const sql = `INSERT INTO event (id, number, status) VALUES (${id},${number}, 'outstanding')`;
```

because in not safe, your id param can contain sql (can read about SQL injection)

after prepare sql -> send it to database and await result,
after obtain result passed it to your callback function

```
(err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message)
            callback(true)
        } else callback(false)
    }
```

in this case you verify if sql successful executed in database

you can read more about it in any documentation about using some SQL in nodejs
as it https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/insert/

Answer (score 0):

db.run(sql, params, (err) => {});

This inbuilt function is taking three particular arguments, where
First one is the sql query having question marks as an identifier for the dynamic values to be passed as an array in the second argument.
Second one is the array having values similar to order and size, in which question mark is present in the sql query
third one is just the callback function, which is called post-execution of your query.

While executing, all the question-marks present in the query will be replaced by the values present in second argument.

Hence, if you're passing [id,number] as the second argument. Then the first question mark picks up the value of id, and second one becomes number.